# QCoreApplication doesn't terminate gracefully

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm a PyQt5 newbie. I've written a simple CLI script that makes a GET request, prints the result, then exits with an error:
"QWaitCondition: Destroyed while threads are still waiting"

What am I doing wrong? My code is shown below:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QObject, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QNetworkRequest, QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkReply
import sys

class MainWindow(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        target = "http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/index.html"
        request = QNetworkRequest(QUrl(target))

        self.networkAccessManager = QNetworkAccessManager()
        #self.networkAccessManager.finished[QNetworkReply].connect(self.headsUp)
        self.networkAccessManager.finished.connect(self.onFinished)
        self.networkAccessManager.get(request)

    def onFinished(self, response): #response is an object of type QNetworkReply
        error = response.error()

        if (error == QNetworkReply.NoError):
            result = response.readAll()
            print(response.header(QNetworkRequest.ContentTypeHeader))
            print(response.header(QNetworkRequest.LastModifiedHeader))
            print(response.header(QNetworkRequest.ContentLengthHeader))
        else:
            print("There was an error. "+response.errorString())

        self.windUp(response)        

    def windUp(self, replyObject): #replyObject is an object of type QNetworkReply
        print("Done")
        replyObject.deleteLater()
        QCoreApplication.quit()       


if __name__ == '__main__':

    qApp = QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(qApp.exec_())
```

Comment: Why do you use a thread when QtNetwork is asynchronous?

Comment: @eyllanesc I've run the script without the thread and it works, but I keep getting an "QWaitCondition: Destroyed while threads are still waiting" error. I thought of using threads to avoid this error.

Comment: the thread is not the solution, you could show that code to indicate where the error is.

Comment: @eyllanesc I've updated my code.

Comment: I do not get any error message, just that nothing is obtained because the link points to an http url that redirects to an https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your code I do not get any error, only I get an empty answer.

```
text/html
None
0
Done
```

And it is correct because in that url there is nothing of content since if you use a browser we will see that it redirects us to another url: `https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/`, so to enable that redirection the `RedirectionTargetAttribute` attribute of reply is analyzed.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtNetwork


class MainWindow(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        target = "http://pyqt.sourceforge.net"
        self.manager = QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager(self)
        self.manager.finished.connect(self.on_finished)
        self.start_request(target)

    def start_request(self, url):
        request = QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest(QtCore.QUrl(url))
        self.manager.get(request)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtNetwork.QNetworkReply)
    def on_finished(self, reply):
        redirection_target = reply.attribute(QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest.RedirectionTargetAttribute)
        if reply.error():
            print("There was an error. {}".format(response.errorString()))
        elif redirection_target is not None:
            reply.deleteLater()
            print("redirection_target: {}".format(redirection_target))
            self.start_request(redirection_target)
        else:
            print(reply.header(QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest.ContentTypeHeader))
            print(reply.header(QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest.LastModifiedHeader))
            print(reply.header(QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest.ContentLengthHeader))
            print(reply.readAll())
            reply.deleteLater()
            QtCore.QCoreApplication.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output:

```
redirection_target: PyQt5.QtCore.QUrl('https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/')
text/html; charset=utf-8
None
None
b'<!doctype html>\n<!-- Server: sfs-consume-8 -->\n<html class="no-js" lang="en">\n    <head>\n        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><script type="text/...
```

Comment: Are you running it in a REPL? Please run it as a script. I've updated the URL to something that is http only and will not redirect. See the original script. Maybe it's my network or something, but my last line is "QWaitCondition: Destroyed while threads are still waiting". It's not a hard error, but the interpreter complains about premature termination.

Comment: @user1801060 Do not execute it in the python interpreter, this kind of scripts do not work in that kind of environments since Qt creates an eventloop that can generate that type of behavior since the REPL expects the execution of a command to be fast, but the eventloop It has an unlimited life cycle. Execute it in the terminal

Comment: I am executing from the CLI. See screenshot here: https://imgur.com/hEQbAYH

Comment: it seems to me that your installation could be the cause of the problem, you could add the python.exe PATH to the environment variables, and secondly indicate how you have installed pyqt5

Comment: Really weird. I tested it on a VPS and it works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user1801060 Change the title of your question since your question does not refer to threads.